# Sorting excel CSV by column, saving and closing - with batch or powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file, cmd, columnsorting

I am using a bat file to open a daily-generated Excel file named 'YYYYMMDD_foo.csv' using batch - this works fine, but I am also trying to group sort the Excel file by one of it's columns - say Column C (Dept.).

```
ID, Name, Dept.
001, Greg, Maths
002, Sue, Operations
003, Bob, Academics
004, Joan, Operations
```

How could I accomplish this sort in batch, so that the file is opened, and then sorted as such?

```
ID, Name, Dept.
003, Bob, Academics
001, Greg, Maths
002, Sue, Operations
004, Joan, Operations
```

Thank you kindly

EDIT: I have attempted to find a solution with Powershell and with Batch - I will post my scripts below and hopefully with will reopen my question.

Powershell:

```
$FilePath = "C:\exceltest\20191203Records.csv"

$rawDate = Get-Date
$year = $rawDate.toString('yyyy')
$month = $rawDate.toString('mm')
$day = $rawDate.toString('dd')



$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$objExcel.Visible = $true
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = $true

$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)

$WorkBook | Sort-Object Program

$WorkBook.Save()

Start-Sleep -s 30
```

Batch:

```
@echo off

SET dY=%DATE:~0,4%
SET dM=%DATE:~5,2%
SET dD=%DATE:~8,2%
SET searchString=%dY%%dM%%dD%Records.csv
SET thePath=C:\exceltest\

echo %thePath%%searchString%

start Excel.exe %thePath%%searchString%
PAUSE
```

Comment: Please **don't [double-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59167166)**!! Edit the original question instead, following the [help], then is will very likely be reopened...

Comment: Hello aschipfl, my apologies for double-posting, I tried to edit the original question but it remained closed.

Comment: it takes some time since some reopen votes are needed. Anyway, since this one has been answered meanwhile, please delete the other one! When done I should be able to remove the "duplicate" state (so please let me know then). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use Excel to sort the List. This can be done directly with Powershell. 
Below example reads the file, sort it by column "Dept." and writes it into an new CSV-File that can be opened in Excel directly.

```
#Make sure to use MM for Month, mm is Minutes
$dateString = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

$filepath= "C:\temp\" + $dateString + "_foo.csv"
$list = Import-Csv -LiteralPath $filepath -Delimiter ","

$outPutFilePath = "C:\temp\"+$dateString+"_sorted.csv"

#sort the List and Export it into CSV-File. Use ; so excel will directly open it correctly
$list | Sort-Object -Property "Dept." | Export-Csv -LiteralPath $outPutFilePath -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you benniz, exactly what I was looking for, I will give this a shot!

Comment: @benniz FYI. You comment that you need to use delimiter `;` so Excel will open on double-click. Actually, this is determined by the Windows locale setting, so it may vary in other parts of the world. In this case better use the `-UseCulture` switch to automatically use the delimiter set for the system (and thus used by Excel). Behind the scenes, this switch will get the system's delimiter using `(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ListSeparator`.

Comment: hah good to know about the -UseCulture switch. I was not aware of that one. Thx